# How to get unique token(id) of authorized user?

Tags: node.js, express

I need unique thing when user log in. This id should be refreshed after log out and log in again but when user closes browser or refreshes page id's not changed 
How could i get unique id from res.cookie ? Help

Answer (score 1):

Unique token is not bundled with expressJS. If you want to implement token-based authorization you can checkout [JWT package](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken). You can also read more about jwt on [this site](http://jwt.io/introduction/)

You can read about a tutorial here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens

Comment: var cert = fs.readFileSync('private.key'); | fs is undefined / maybe i don't need to use private.key? smth like jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, '44fg4g', { algorithm: 'RS256'}) to create token? but fs, what is fs?

Comment: FS (File System) Is a native node_module form nodeJS. It is used for reading files on your filesystem. Anyway, you can start with a simple algorithm (HS256). I've updated my answer and added a tutorial.

Comment: var basicAuth  = require('basic-auth'); is same? Can i get unigue token with it too?

Comment: I don't know where you got the basic-auth